# How to improve hough transform for line detection?

Tags: probability, distributions, matlab, computer-vision

I'm looking for a method to detect false observations inside the hough transformation space, even called line detection algorithm.

The hough space can be described as this

[image]

X-axis is radius and Y-axis is the angle of the equation

$$xsin(\theta) + ycos(\theta) = \rho$$

Which is the straight line equation, but expressed as an angle.

$$y = K*x + M$$

To understand hough space, watch the following videos
https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=XRBc_xkZREg&ab_channel=FirstPrinciplesofComputerVision
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zAT6yTHvP0&ab_channel=DigitalSreeni

This is how the result looks like. The red arrows points at the false observation.

[image]

**Question:**

The problem with hough transform is false observations. In the image, I have marked the false observations (coordinates for angle $\theta$ and radius $\rho$) as read. But the problem is that I need to find a method that can avoid my algorithm to assume that these are perfect lines.

Do you have any suggestion how to improve hough transform for line detection?
One way is to use statistics and mahalanobis distance, but which statistical method?

**How to reproduce this issue:**

Use this code and uncomment this line

```
%    surf(P, [360:1000]);
%figure
```

Inside this function

```
function [K, M, R, T] = hough(varargin)
  % Check if there is any input
  if(isempty(varargin))
    error('Missing inputs')
  end

  % Get data matrix X
  if(length(varargin) >= 1)
    X = varargin{1};
  else
    error('Missing data X')
  end

  % Get amount of sloped lines
  if(length(varargin) >= 2)
    N = varargin{2};
  else
    error('Missing amount of sloped lines')
  end

  % Get amount of sloped lines
  if(length(varargin) >= 3)
    radius = varargin{3};
  else
    radius = 10;
  end

  % Compute scores for the lines
  P = compute_scores(X);

  % Compute lines
  [K, M, R, T] = compute_lines(P, N, radius);
end

function P = compute_scores(X)
  % Get the size of X
  [m, n] = size(X);

  % Choose angles between -90 and 90 in radians with 1 degree in step
  angles = -90:1:90;

  % Compute slope Kk for every angle
  Kk = tan(deg2rad(angles));

  % Get length of Kk
  Kk_length = length(Kk);

  % Create the longest distance inside the edge image X
  R = ceil(sqrt(m^2 + n^2)) + 1;

  % Create points holder P
  P = zeros(361, R);

  % Collect the points for the most common lines
  for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
      % Check if the coordinate X(i, j) belongs to an edge
      if(X(i, j) <= eps)
        % No edge here
        continue
      end

      % Compute Mk from straight line equation
      Mk = j - Kk*i;

      % Find minimal x
      x = -Kk.*Mk./(1 + Kk.^2);

      % Compute y
      y = Kk.*x + Mk;

      % Compute r and make it to an integer
      r = floor(sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2)) + 1; % + 1 is just for indexing

      % Compute theta and make sure theta is not negative
      theta = 180 + rad2deg(atan2(y, x));
      theta = floor(theta) + 1; % + 1 is just for indexing

      % Sometimes r kan be larger than R
      theta(r > R) = [];
      r(r > R) = [];

      % Add + 1
      indices = sub2ind(size(P), theta, r);
      P(indices) = P(indices) + 1;
    end
  end

  % This is the non vectorized code
  %for i = 1:m
  %  for j = 1:n
      % Check if the coordinate X(i, j) belongs to an edge
  %    if(X(i, j) <= eps)
        % No edge here
  %      continue
  %    end

      % Compute the r and theta from the pixel
  %    for k = 1:Kk_length
        % Compute Mk from straight line equation
  %      Mk = j - Kk(k)*i;

        % Find minimal x
  %      x = -Kk(k)*Mk/(1 + Kk(k)^2);

        % Compute y
  %      y = Kk(k)*x + Mk;

        % Compute r and make it to an integer
  %      r = floor(sqrt(x^2 + y^2)) + 1; % + 1 is just for indexing

        % Compute theta and make sure theta is not negative
  %      theta = 180 + rad2deg(atan2(y, x));
  %      theta = floor(theta) + 1; % + 1 is just for indexing

        % Sometimes r kan be larger than R
  %      if(r <= R)
  %        P(theta, r) = P(theta, r) + 1;
  %      end
  %    end
  %  end
  %end
end

function [K, M, R, T] = compute_lines(P, N, radius)

%    surf(P, [360:1000]);
%figure
  % Update size for P
  [m, n] = size(P);

  % Sort P as it was a vector
  [~, index] = sort(P(:), 'descend');

  % Create K, M, R and T - They are holders for the output
  K = zeros(1, N);
  M = zeros(1, N);
  R = zeros(1, N);
  T = zeros(1, N);

  % Fill K and M
  count = 1;
  for k = 1:m*n
    % Find the theta and r for the N largest value
    [theta, r] = ind2sub([m, n], index(k));

    % Take minus 180 because we did + 180 above
    theta = theta - 180;

    % Check if it's not the same theta and r again
    if(k > 1)
      if(compute_violate(theta, r, T, R, radius))
        continue
      end
    end

    % y = k*x + m can be expressed as x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta) = r
    v = deg2rad(theta);
    K(count) = sin(v)/-cos(v);
    M(count) = - r/-cos(v);
    R(count) = r;
    T(count) = theta;

    % Count
    count = count + 1;
    if(count > N)
      break;
    end
  end
end

function violate = compute_violate(theta, r, T, R, radius)
  % Check if they violate
  theta_violate = abs(theta - T) < radius;
  r_violate = abs(r - R) < radius;

  % Check if they both violate
  violate = and(length(find(r_violate > 0)), length(find(theta_violate > 0)));

  %  violate = false;
  %  for j = 1:count
  %    % Find the difference
  %    x = abs(theta - T(j));
  %    y = abs(r - R(j));

       % Check the difference is lower than radius
  %    if(and(x < radius, y < radius))
  %      violate = true;
  %      break;
  %    end
  %  end
end
```

And the working example

```
% Clear
clear all
close all
clc

% Read image
X = imread('test_hough.png');

% If the image is color
if(size(X, 3) > 1)
  X = rgb2gray(X);
end

% Plot the image
imshow(X);

% Do hough transform
N = 5; % Number of lines
radius = 10; % This tuning parameter prevents the algorithm to re-select the same line again
[K, M, R] = mi.hough(X, N, radius);

% Plot the lines together with the image
[~, n] = size(X);
x = linspace(0, n);
hold on
for i = 1:N
  y = K(i)*x + M(i);
  plot(x, y)
end
```

With the image `test_hough.png`

[image]